# How to mount a ConfigMap as a file without using volume

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

The aim behind this question is to know how having a file inside a Pod, if we use ConfigMap, I don't want to apply changes if the configMap will change

Thanks

Comment: Can't clearly get what exactly you are asking for. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I want to have a file created inside a pod but i don't want to receive the configmap updates

Comment: If you mount configmap as a file inside your pod. The changes that you make in configmap will get reflected as soon as you do `kubectl apply`. But the process  (or application) running inside your pod will not get updated config from configmap. You need to restart the pod to get updated config reflected from configmap.

Comment: I don't want to get updates, How to consume a configMap *not in volume ?

Comment: Without using volume you won't be able to copy data from configmap inside your pod. Please carefully go through this document https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/ Also want to know what is you exact usecase here.

Comment: Imagine that we have multiple pods, they receive a common configuration (d'où la configmap), so my purpose is to change a configuration for a specific pod only and that using a file, that's it

Comment: You can copy from configmap to your pod by importing variables of interest from your configmap as env using configMapKeyRef.

What you are wanting to do can be achieved by using a service declaration over different deployment pods. Then you can be selective around which pod's configmap you want to change.

Comment: “A container using a ConfigMap as a subPath volume will not receive ConfigMap updates.” [[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically)] This is a limitation when using `subPath`, prob not the ideal behavior, but it’s how k8s works today and seems to meet your (unconventional) requirement. If the ConfigMap is updated while the pod is running, the file will not get the update. But if the pod is recreated, for instance, you’ll likely see the update. This is ultimately a temporary and brittle solution.

Answer (score 5):

I am not really understanding, why don't you want to use a volume? 
A proper way, to mount a confgimap to a pod looks like this:
Configmap- specify name of the file in a `data` section:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2016-02-18T18:52:05Z
  name: txt-file-configmap
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "516"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/game-config
  uid: b4952dc3-d670-11e5-8cd0-68f728db1985
data:
  file.txt: |
    here
    are
    filecontents
```

And in a pod, specify a volume with a configmap name and volumeMount, pointing a path, where to mount the volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /etc/txtfiles/file.txt" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: txt-file
        mountPath: /etc/txtfiles
  volumes:
    - name: txt-file
      configMap:
        name: txt-file-configmap
```

The example pod which I provided you, will have the configmap mounted as a file and will print it's contents.

Comment: The pod contents won't change, untill you won't restart it.

Comment: so, if I make an update to ConfigMap, do these changes will be applied in the pod volume?

Comment: Volume is mounted on the pod start. So, if you will make changes in the configmap, changes will apply after the pod restart. Why don't you want the changes to be applied? That looks like an unusual problem!

Comment: see the comments above, plz

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a file inside a pod but you don't want to get that updated if the config map is updated. So you can not use configmap because it will update files if pod restart.

So the only option I can think to push file after the pod is created something like "kubectl cp" command to copy a file to the pod.

```
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

The problem will be when pod restarted the file be gone so you have to automate it by somehow one way,

Below is using init container.

you can put the file in some XYZ location and download it by init container.

```
  initContainers:
  - name: download-conf
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'curl http://exampel.com/conf.file -o statfull.conf']
```

NOTE:- This is an just approach code have't tested